# Warped siding letting mice in

Tags: siding, caulking

Some of my 40yo T1-11 siding has warped leaving gaps at the bottom between it and the house. I think mice may be entering through these. I was told not to caulk because moisture might build up. Other than replacement are there options?

Comment: Welcome!  How big are the gaps?  How widespread?  What's your geographic location?

Comment: Could you share some pictures of your siding and the gaps? It's often much easier to recommend a fix when we can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Re-nail the bottom of the T1-11 to the sill plate every 6 inches. I use Simpson StrongTie ring shank stainless steel siding nails. Be sure you know where any water pipes and drain lines are in the exterior wall, and use the length of nail that would not go much more than 1 inch into the sill plate. You could go 1.5 inches into studs low on the walls where there would be no pipes or wires.

[Simpson StrongTie stainless steel siding nails](https://wholesalepowertools.com/simpson-strong-tie-t5snd1-316-stainless-steel-wood-siding-nail-083-dia-x-1-3-4-length-5d-14-ga-1-lb?gclid=Cj0KCQjwk_TbBRDsARIsAALJSObcwBjbmfC5MynFT3vOYo-VZ3BsdiinBsqbZCENyYaUFE-4rhzmHHYaArfWEALw_wcB#.W331pM5Kh0w)